# How to have two side by side divs align to bottom?

Tags: html, css, positioning

Instead of Figure 1, I would like Figure 2. In Figure 1, the menu and image are aligned to the top, but I would like them to be aligned to bottom.
[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

Here is my CSS:

```
 <div id="branding">
      <div class="brand-left"></div>
      <div class="brand-right"></div>
 </div>

#branding {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.brand-left {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 730px;
}

.brand-right {
    text-align: right;
    width: 222px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried inserting those inside a "table-cell" and `vertical-align:bottom`? - which can also be a div with CSS: `display:table-cell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this and ultimately it depends on what you're trying to accomplish and what your project requirements are (e.g. browser support). That said, one way is to position the element you want bottom aligned absolutely.

1. First, assign your branding container a `position: relative;` property and value
2. Second, float your logo right
3. Third, assign your container to which you want bottom aligned a `position: absolute;` property and value

Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/mjoanisse/pen/grvBwE

Comment: While this one worked (for old browsers support), I would also recommend Chris's answer using flex.

Comment: I agree, flex is amazing; however, as mentioned, it will depend on the project specs. But, even with older browsers, you can still use flex in combination with Modernizr to detect support and a polyfill stylesheet.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution 1 (using flex)

You can achieve this behavior using `display: flex`. All you have to do is add this rules to your `branding` div:

```
#branding {
    display: flex; /* ADDED */
    align-items: flex-end; /* ADDED */
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green; 
}
```

Here is a snippet

```css
#branding {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

#branding > div{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.brand-left {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 730px;
}

.brand-right {
    text-align: right;
    width: 222px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="branding">
        <div class="brand-left">content</div>
        <div class="brand-right">
          <img src="http://senda-arcoiris.info/images/100x100.gif"/>
        </div>
</div>
```

---

## Solution 2 (using position relative/absolute)

Another solution without using `flex` would be removing the `floats` from child divs and position them absolute. Please see the snippet below:

```css
#branding {
    position: absolute;      /* ADDED */
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

#branding > div{
  position: relative;       /* ADDED */
  display: inline-block;    /* ADDED */
  border: 1px solid blue;
  bottom: 0;
}

.brand-left {
    width: 330px;  /* I changed the width in order to fit in the snippet */
}

.brand-right {
    text-align: right;
    width: 222px;
}
```

```html
<div id="branding">
        <div class="brand-left">content</div>
        <div class="brand-right">
          <img src="http://senda-arcoiris.info/images/100x100.gif"/>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really like this answer, but we also need to support some old browsers. From the documentation, it seems "flex" is not supported on older versions of browsers....

Comment: there is another solution, just let me write it

Comment: Thanks Chris, that was a very well written answer, but one of the other solutions worked for me. Still upvoted!!!

Comment: @coffeeak glad if I helped

Answer (score 1):

you can try it with flexbox

```css
#branding{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  height:250px;
    background-color:green;
    align-items:flex-end;
}




.brand-left {
    position: relative;
    width: 730px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:pink;
}

.brand-right {
    text-align: right;
    width: 222px;
     background-color:blue;
     height:250px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="branding">
        <div class="brand-left"></div>
        <div class="brand-right"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `display: flex;`

```css
.bottom {
  display: flex;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
 }

.right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `line-height` in your `.brand-left div`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case interested in without `display: flex`

```css
#branding {
  width: 100%;
}
.brand-left {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 750px;
  background: #f00;
  min-height: 250px;
}
.brand-left .nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 15px;
}
.brand-left .nav li {
  display: inline;
}
.brand-right {
  text-align: right;
  width: 222px;
  float: left;
  background: #ff0;
  min-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="branding">
  <div class="brand-left">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Registration</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Log In</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="brand-right"></div>
</div>
```